# parse.com get Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I am displaying some results from Parse on a website but currently the loop is breaking because not all the columns have values in them.

```
var warningCreator = object.get("creator").get("country");
```

There are some instances where the user has not selected their country and that results in this error.

I am wondering if there is any way to check whether the result is undefined before calling it.

For iOs I found:

```
if ([object objectForKey:@"keyPath"]) {
  // the object has a value for key keyPath
}
```

Is there anything simialar for the javaScript SDK?

*Edit (Added more code for clarity):

```
        var WarningPoints = Parse.Object.extend("Warning_Point");
        var query = new Parse.Query("Warning_Point");

        query.include("creator");
        query.include("position");

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                markerCount = 0;

                if (results.length == 0) {
                    alert('There are Warning Points found for specified parameters.')
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                    var object = results[i];

                    var warningCreator = object.get("creator").get("country");

                    var warningLat = object.get("position").get("lat");
                    var warningLong = object.get("position").get("long");

                    if((object.get("position").get("address"))!=null){
                        warningAddress = object.get("position").get("address");
                    }

                    console.log(warningAddress);

                    var warningName = object.get("name");

                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
```

The exact error in console is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - and the line of the error is:   warningCreator = object.get("creator").get("country");

Comment: just try to check the null or empty value or UNDEFINED...

Comment: The probelem is when doing the check, the error is triggered, see below:

                    if((object.get("creator").get("country"))!=null){
                      warningCreator = object.get("creator").get("country");
                    }

Comment: i think you need to do 2 checks. 1 for creator and other for checking country. The two values can be null/empty.

Comment: If you add the above as an answer, I can mark it correct as that is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(object['keyPath']!=null){
 //the object has a value for key keyPath
}
```

Where object is the variable that contains your data retrieved from parse.
You can be more accurate in your condition checking for empty values too.

In your case:

```
if(object.get("creator")!=null && object.get("creator").get("country")!=null){
 //the fields have a value
}
else{
 //Some field is null
}
```

You need to do a check for each .get("field") in your statement because each field can be null.

You have 2 nested .get().get() and probably the first one is returning null so it raises the exception.

Comment: How would I use this for for a relational object, like object.get("creator").get("country");

Comment: Can you put more code? how do you obtain the "object" var? it would help me in order to give you a better answer

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help.

Sometimes you just need the opinion of some fresh eyes to freshen your views again.

```
if(object.get("creator") != null ){
                    if(object.get("creator").get("country") != null ){
                        var warningCreator = object.get("creator").get("country");
                    }
                }

                if(object.get("position") != null ){
                    if(object.get("position").get("lat") != null ){
                           var warningLat = object.get("position").get("lat");
                    }
                }

                if(object.get("position") != null ){
                    if(object.get("position").get("long") != null ){
                          var warningLong = object.get("position").get("long");
                    }
                }

                if(object.get("position") != null ){
                    if(object.get("position").get("address") != null ){
                         var warningAddress = object.get("position").get("address");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i do the same in one if statement and i add the explanation of the nested checks. It is enough for your vote?